# Android Custom View Problem

Tags: android, view

Hi Guys i have been fighting with this problem and don't know what is the reason. I have a simple layout as follows
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" class="com.dinash.notepad.NotePade$LinedEditText" />`

and the activity class is as follows:

```
public class NotePade extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;
    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        // mPaint.setColor(R.color.edit_note_line); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR
        // HERE
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED); // SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // int count = getLineCount();
        int height = getHeight();
        // int height = 100;
        int line_height = getLineHeight();
        int count = height / line_height;
        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();// for long text with scrolling

        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);// first line
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1,
                    paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();// next line
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

}

when i launch the application i keep on getting this error`05-26 11:31:21.604: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1537): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.dinash.notepad.NotePade$LinedEditText`

and following that

`05-26 11:31:21.604: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1537): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: LinedEditText(Context,AttributeSet)`

Could any body tel what the problem is...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your inner class static. Otherwise, it would always require an instance of NotePade to give it an initialization context.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying).

Answer (score 1):

Move your custom view into separate file.

Answer (score 1):

I think write your custom view in a separate class and your layout should be like this...

```
<com.dinash.notepad.LinedEditText></com.dinash.notepad.LinedEditText>
```